# how using key(name) we will get output value(Address) in a .csv or .xls file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sl. No.,Name,Address

1.,Stuart,Wall Street

2.,Charlie,Broadway

3.,Oliver,Hollywood Boulevard

4.,Harry,Las Vegas Boulevard

5.,Kyle,Bourbon Street

o/p will be like:

```
print(Stuart) >>>  Wall Street
```

Comment: How `New York City, New York` related to `Sturart` ?

Comment: your source is a json file ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import csv into `pandas dataframe` and use `loc`

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/prince/Downloads/test2.csv', sep=',')
df = df.set_index('Name')
print(df.loc['Stuart']['Address'])
```

which gives the following output

```
Wall Street
```